# TFS Merging Conflicts on TFVS

Tags: git, azure, tfs, tfvc

I am using Azure & TFS or tfvs and managing different branches for a long time and I love to use this but with passage of time I thing that **CVCS** (Centralized Version Control System) have some major drawbacks which I am facing now a days in an organization.

Real live scenario and hope you are also working and facing them,

> I have a single project called 'ProjA' and 5 developers are working on
>   the 'ProjA', 2 new requirements came from customer to add new functionalities
>   on login page
>
> 1) Task 1- Forgot Username
>
> 2) Task 2- Forgot Password

Task1 assigned to Developer1 and Task2 assigned to Developer2 
both developers starts there work on same resource means same login.aspx and .cs page

Task1 completed and checkIn in to the repository and moved into the QA branch and published on an QA environment, after day Developer2 finshed his task and checkin his code while checkin he will first take the fresh cope(getlatest) of the page from the server, merge his changes after verification and checkIn the code, move to QA branch, means now tfvs have both developers changesets and changes,

Now Client says that only Task2 (Forgot Password) will be move to Production and for the time being Task1 (Forgot Username) holds on,

> **Problem Statement**: Now How I can move only Developer2 changes into the production and eliminate/skip the Developer1 changes, Keep in mind that both developers worked on same code resource?

This can be done by manually commenting the code of developer1 but its not reliable solution and not for a big and highly available projects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, there is two aspects:

1. Your development process. You should plan/approve your next release with your customer (product owner). If customer says `I want only Task 2- Forgot Password`, you merge only Task 2 to your QA branch. If customer says `I want only Task 1, Task 2`, you merge both tasks to your QA branch. If your customer changed his mind, that will costs additional money to align your release (cut ready features). So, do not merge not approved features to QA )).
2. Technical. With TFVC, you can try the following

   1. [Rollback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/roll-back-changesets?view=azure-devops) your QA branch to the previous state (before Task1) and repeat merge Task 2.
   2. Create another QA branch from production and do [the baseless merge operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/merge-command?view=azure-devops#baseless-merge) from Task 2 branch. Maybe this tool will help you: [MultiMerge.2017](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Jesusfan.MultiMerge2017&ssr=false#overview), [MultiMerge.2019](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Jesusfan.MultiMerge2019).

Comment: thanks for the feed, actually at initially both tasks supposed to move to production at same time but at end of the sprint requirements changed and team moved both tasks in to QA branch so that QA can perform their iteration, Keep it in mind that both developer WORKED ON SAME page.aspx, .cs. and at 11th hour just only one change proceed to the next stage-production, how this possible?

Comment: @SaadAwan I do not see any issues to work with the same items. The complexity depends of your changes consistency. If you see Task 1 and Task 2 as separate change sets, you can consider to use [Roll back changes from a single changeset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/roll-back-changesets?view=azure-devops#roll-back-changes-from-a-single-changeset) of Task 1. If Task 2 contains adaptation to Task 1, that`s may require to cut Task 1 manually.

Comment: yes thats my point we need to eliminate the manual intervention, bex this is just an example the one page and 2 tasks, actual situation is that multiple files which have multiple developers changes, and some are on same changesets and some are on different changesets.